# Why can't my binary search find the passwords I am generating for my array of strings?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class A3 {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {   
        Accept inputScanner = new Accept(); 
        Assign3 sortObj = new Assign3();

        String lname[] = {"","","","",""};
        String psw[] = {"","","","",""};
        String input;

            do
            {   
                System.out.println("Password Generator");           
                System.out.println("Please enter 5 last names:");

                for (int index = 0; index < lname.length; index++)
                {
                    System.out.print("Please enter last name: ");
                    lname[index] = inputScanner.acceptInputString();
                    psw[index] = sortObj.generatePassword(lname, index);                     
                }

                sortObj.sortArrayDescending(lname);             
                sortObj.arrayDisplay(lname, psw);

                Screen.scrollscreen(70, 1, '=');
                System.out.print("Please enter name to search (e or E to exit):");
                input = inputScanner.acceptInputString();
                int password = sortObj.binSrch(lname, input);

                if(password >= 0)
                {                   
                    System.out.println("Name: " + input + " ===> " + "password: " + password);
                    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(input + " is not found");
                    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                }

            }while(input.equals("e") && input.equals("E")); 
    }


    public void sortArrayDescending(String[] lnameArray)
    {   String temp;

        for(int j = 1; j < lnameArray.length - 1; j++)
        {
            for(int index = 0; index < lnameArray.length - 1; index++)
            {
                if(lnameArray[index].trim().compareTo(lnameArray[index+1].trim())<0)
                {
                    temp = lnameArray[index];
                    lnameArray[index] = lnameArray[index + 1];
                    lnameArray[index + 1] = temp;
                }
            }                
        }
    }

    public void arrayDisplay(String lnameContent[], String pswContent[])
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < lnameContent.length; i ++)
        {
            System.out.println(lnameContent[i] + "      "  +  pswContent[i]);
        }
    }

    public int binSrch(String strArr[], String search)
    {           
            int mid = -1;
            int first = 0;
            int last = strArr.length - 1;
            boolean found = false;

            while(first <= last)
            {   
                mid = (first + last) / 2;

                if(strArr[mid].equalsIgnoreCase(search))
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if(strArr[mid].compareToIgnoreCase(search) < 0)
                {
                    last = mid - 1; //use lower half
                }
                else
                {
                    first = mid + 1; //use upper half
                }
            }

            if(!found)
            {
                mid = -1;   
            }

            return mid;

    }

    public String generatePassword(String[] str, int index)        
    {   
        String name = str[index];
        char first = name.charAt(0);
        char last = name.charAt(name.length()-1);
        int mid = 0;

        if(first != last)
        {
            mid = ( ((int)(first) + ((int)(last)) / 2) );
        }
        else 
        {
            mid = ( ((int)(first) + ((int)(last)) / 3) );
        }

        Random rNum = new Random();
        int randomNum = rNum.nextInt(5);
        String password = (first + "" + (char)(mid) + "" + randomNum).toLowerCase();

        return password;
    }

    public void duplicateCheck(String[] password)
    {

    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Password Generator
Please enter 5 last names:
Please enter last name: magnum
Please enter last name: bauer
Please enter last name: sahid
Please enter last name: austen
Please enter last name: reese
sahid       m?0
reese       b?0
magnum      s¥4
bauer       a?0
austen      r¤0
======================================================================
Please enter name to search (e or E to exit):sahid

Name: sahid ===> password: 0     

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

//this line is supposed to print out "m?0" because it is the password
```

that was generated for "sahid" so why is it printing "0"? And how can I make it

print out "m?0" or whatever random password my program generates for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. Remember that `password` is the index of the `psw[]` String Array and not the actual content of the Array.

You just have to write `psw[password]` instead of `password` in the following line:

```
System.out.println("Name: " + input + " ===> " + "password: " + password); 
/* Correction Here : Replace password --> psw[password] */
```

Corrected code snippet:

```
if(password >= 0)
{                   
    System.out.println("Name: " + input + " ===> " + "password: " + psw[password]);
    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
}
```

Now, you should get output as follows:

```
Name: sahid ===> password: m?0
```

**EDIT :** Also, as mentioned by @Gyanapriya you'll have to sort `psw[]` array in addition to the `lname[]` unless you are trying to assign the random passwords to the users.

Comment: After applying the changes suggested by you : don't you think this will still be wrong. The sortDescending function needs to swap elements for both lname and psw to keep the same order as input.

Comment: @Gyanapriya Yes, you are correct unless he is trying to assign the random passwords to the users.